# Issue with Ionic app background service with cordova

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am very new to Ionic app. I wanna run my app in the background process for some timers to find the results about the app.

Here I have a problem is, when I press the back button, the app is getting quit and its not running in the background process.

I tried with Cordova background service installing via npm from github. But its not working as I expected.

Any one can help to get out from this problem?

Comment: How do you expect it to work? Describe your goal and problem.

Comment: Actually, I am using this app for booking the slots for appointment. So the app should be run in the background and it should wait for new bookings and so on. Whenever any new booking got booked it should show the notification in the notification area. so that, the app will wake up and it will act accordingly. For this I am not using any Google cloud or something. The PHP file will keep on running in the app to get the details from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this plugin https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode.

So to install plugin:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode.git
```

Comment: I have used it and the app is showing a alert in the notifications area like "App is running in the background." But for my case, it should not show any notification and its silently should run in the background.

Comment: But the plugin allow to run in a silent mode, see https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode#android-customization